Camera Permission Issue in Next.js
I want to send camera permission to the user, but the permission is not being received. I tried it on my iPhone, and it sent me the permission request, and the camera worked fine. However, it doesn't work on Android. I tried it on several devices. I am using Next.js, and I will share my code.
I used ChatGPT to try to solve the problem, but I couldn't find a solution. I tested the site on several different devices, but the issue only appears on Android devices. Also, I searched on YouTube and watched a video discussing the Kobble library, but I couldn't use it and didn't find any other explanations to clarify how to work with it.

import { useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import jsQR from "jsqr";
import axios from "axios";
// import "./globals.css";

export default function Home() {
  const [qrData, setQrData] = useState("");
  const [cameraActive, setCameraActive] = useState(false);
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [responseMessage, setResponseMessage] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const apiUrl = "https://example.com/api";

  // Request camera access permission
  const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: { facingMode: "environment" },
      });
      setCameraPermission(true);
      setCameraActive(true);
      stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Camera access denied:", err);
      setCameraPermission(false);
      alert("Please allow camera access from the browser settings.");
    }
  };

  // Capture image and scan QR code
  const captureAndScanQRCode = useCallback(async () => {
    const video = webcamRef.current.video;
    if (video) {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      const code = jsQR(imageData.data, imageData.width, imageData.height);

      if (code) {
        setQrData(code.data);
        console.log("Code scanned:", code.data);

        // Send data to server for verification
        try {
          setLoading(true);
          const response = await axios.post(`${apiUrl}/check-qr`, {
            qrData: code.data,
          });
          setResponseMessage(response.data.message);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error sending data:", error);
          setResponseMessage("Failed to verify QR Code.");
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      } else {
        alert(
          "No QR Code found. Please ensure the code is clear and try again."
        );
      }
    }
  }, [webcamRef]);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-4 w-full h-dvh relative px-4">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">Scan QR Ticket</h1>

      {cameraPermission === null ? (
        <button
          onClick={requestCameraPermission}
          className="bg-neutral-200 text-black rounded-lg px-4 py-1 max-w-lg w-full"
        >
          Request Camera Permission
        </button>
      ) : cameraPermission ? (
        <>
          <Webcam
            audio={false}
            ref={webcamRef}
            screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
            width={384}
            className="rounded-2xl aspect-square object-cover sm:w-96 w-full"
            videoConstraints={{
              facingMode: "environment",
            }}
          />
          <button
            onClick={captureAndScanQRCode}
            className="bg-black text-white rounded-xl px-2 py-2 mt-4 aspect-square object-cover flex items-center justify-center"
          >
            <svg
              width="800px"
              height="800px"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              fill="none"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              className="w-10 h-10 inline-block"
            >
              <path
                d="M12 16C13.6569 16 15 14.6569 15 13C15 11.3431 13.6569 10 12 10C10.3431 10 9 11.3431 9 13C9 14.6569 10.3431 16 12 16Z"
                stroke="#ffffff"
                strokeWidth="2"
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
              />
              <path
                d="M3 16.8V9.2C3 8.0799 3 7.51984 3.21799 7.09202C3.40973 6.71569 3.71569 6.40973 4.09202 6.21799C4.51984 6 5.0799 6 6.2 6H7.25464C7.37758 6 7.43905 6 7.49576 5.9935C7.79166 5.95961 8.05705 5.79559 8.21969 5.54609C8.25086 5.49827 8.27836 5.44328 8.33333 5.33333C8.44329 5.11342 8.49827 5.00346 8.56062 4.90782C8.8859 4.40882 9.41668 4.08078 10.0085 4.01299C10.1219 4 10.2448 4 10.4907 4H13.5093C13.7552 4 13.8781 4 13.9915 4.01299C14.5833 4.08078 15.1141 4.40882 15.4394 4.90782C15.5017 5.00345 15.5567 5.11345 15.6667 5.33333C15.7216 5.44329 15.7491 5.49827 15.7803 5.54609C15.943 5.79559 16.2083 5.95961 16.5042 5.9935C16.561 6 16.6224 6 16.7454 6H17.8C18.9201 6 19.4802 6 19.908 6.21799C20.2843 6.40973 20.5903 6.71569 20.782 7.09202C21 7.51984 21 8.0799 21 9.2V16.8C21 17.9201 21 18.4802 20.782 18.908C20.5903 19.2843 20.2843 19.5903 19.908 19.782C19.4802 20 18.9201 20 17.8 20H6.2C5.0799 20 4.51984 20 4.09202 19.782C3.71569 19.5903 3.40973 19.2843 3.21799 18.908C3 18.4802 3 17.9201 3 16.8Z"
                stroke="#ffffff"
                strokeWidth="2"
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
              />
            </svg>
          </button>
          {/* <p>Scanned data: {qrData ? "Found data." : "No data found yet."}</p> */}
          {loading ? (
            <div class="loader"></div>
          ) : responseMessage === "Used-successfully" ? (
            <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-dvh flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-[#00000030] backdrop-blur-md">
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setResponseMessage(null);
                  setQrData(null);
                }}
                className="absolute top-4 right-4 bg-black text-white text-sm px-4 py-1 rounded-lg"
              >
                Close
              </button>
              <div className="min-w-96 bg-[#eceeec] rounded-3xl p-4 flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
                <p>✅ User is allowed to enter the event.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : responseMessage === "Used-previously" ? (
            <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-dvh flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-[#00000030] backdrop-blur-md">
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setResponseMessage(null);
                  setQrData(null);
                }}
                className="absolute top-4 right-4 bg-black text-white text-sm px-4 py-1 rounded-lg"
              >
                Close
              </button>
              <div className="min-w-96 bg-[#eceeec] rounded-3xl p-4 flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
                <p>❌ User is not authorized to enter the event.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <p>{responseMessage}</p>
          )}
        </>
      ) : (
        <p>Please allow camera access to use this feature.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}````


When you create the stream, do you get an exception? If so, have you traced the flow of this code up until the point that it stops?

Consider also removing facingMode for now; that is a requirement per the docs. Maybe you just need to focus on getting any permissions for now.
